# What is the meaning of "advice confirms" in a bank statement?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, bank-account, wire-transfer

I got some money transferred from a company in the USA to my UK bank (HSBC) account and I found that it is listed as "advice confirms" in the bank statement record online.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you are expected to have received a separate piece of communication ("advice") which confirms who the payment came from. This is common with CHAPS payments and overseas transactions.

Comment: So this is not a problem in the payment and should be updated when they confirm the sender name, correct?

Comment: This is not a problem in the payment, correct. As to whether they will update it, I don't think so.